# Flutter-Supabase Admin page to create new users and set passwords for them

Tags: android, flutter, supabase, supabase-database

I am working on an app that requires a page for the admin in which the admin can create users, by entering their name, email, password and department. I am able to register the user with this page but as soon as the new user gets registered I get logged out of the Admin account and I am logged in with id of the user i just created, here is my code for the method used to create users by the admin.

is there any other way i can do this??

Future registerEmployeeMaster(
String email, String name, String password, int? department, bool isAdmin,
BuildContext context) async {
try {
setIsLoading = true;
if (email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty || name.isEmpty || department == null) {
throw Exception("Name, Email, and Password are mandatory fields.");
}

```
      // Sign up the user
  final AuthResponse response = await _supabase.auth.signUp(
    email: email,
    password: password,
  );

  if (response.user != null) {
    await insertNewUser(email, response.user!.id, department);
    await _supabase.from(Constants.employeeTable).update(
        {'name': name, 'department': employeeDepartment},
      ).eq('id', response.user!.id);
   Utils.showSnackBar(
        "Successfully registered!",
        context,
        color: Colors.green,
      );
     }
} catch (e) {
  // Show a detailed error message to the user
  Utils.showSnackBar("Error: ${e.toString()}", context, color: Colors.red);
} finally {
  setIsLoading = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a user without you being signed in as the user that you created, you need to create them on a backend using the admin `createUser` method.
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-admin-createuser

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.admin.createUser({
  email: 'user@email.com',
  password: 'password',
  user_metadata: { name: 'Yoda' }
})
```

You can use the Supabase's edge functions to create a backend if you want to keep everything Supabase ecosystem. Otherwise, any backend will be fine.

You can use Dart Edge if you want to write your backend in Dart instead of Typescript.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/dart-edge